# react-native-navigation (wix) v2 static Scene for all tabs

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

We are developing an app which will have a music player (similar to spotify).
Even tho React-navigation worked, we thought about switching to React-native-navigation (v2) from wix.
While implementing RNN v2 we had the problem to place a component above the bottomTabs Bar so that it will stay static while the tabs switch. 
We dont want the component to rerender with switching Tabs. It should behave similar to spotifys music player!
Is that possible?

tl;dr

How can I place a component (e.g. a music player) just above the bottomTabs. It should not rerender with switching tabs.

thanks a lot for your help

**update**

this worked for me:

```
Navigation.showOverlay({
  component: {
    name: 'yourRegisteredScene',
    passProps: {
    },
    options: {
      overlay: {
        interceptTouchOutside: false,
      },
      layout: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        orientation: ['portrait'],
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RNN v2 has an overlay API which allows you to show a component as an overlay above the whole app. If you don't dismiss the overlay, it will persistently show even when you switch between tabs.

I'm not sure if it meets all your needs but you can give it a try. 
Take a look at the [documentation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/v2/#/docs/top-level-api?id=showoverlaylayout-) for more info. There's also an [example](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/blob/v2/playground/src/screens/OptionsScreen.js#L258) in the playground project.

Comment: But we have one open question left: Our component must me able to expand. Like the Player in Spotify. Is there a possiblity to change the size of the overlay on the fly while interacting? e.g. you drag the component and the component expands to fullscreen.  Do I have to make the overlay fullscreen? And if so, how can I still interact with the underlying bottomTabs?

Comment: The overlay can change its size like any other component. It can also take the whole screen, so you can expand it only when necessary. The only problematic thing as I see it is the issue of positioning the component correctly above the tabs in a way that supports all use-cases. That’s why I said that I’m not sure if it will meet all your needs, you’ll need to play with it and see for yourself

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot anyway. I will try it this way and will see if its possible !

Comment: is there a way to slide-in the overlay ? and i could not find the available options for this method in the documentation!! any hints please ?